# What is the way that LiveISOs are made?

Tags: custom-distributions

Every customization of Ubuntu ISO talks about reusing an existing LiveISO.
But how are the LiveISOs being built in the first place? I doubt they do a recursive build from previous revision.
I've been trying to use LiveBuild (debian builder, which is available in ubuntu repos) but I keep getting errors (like "E: The repository 'file:/root/packages ./ Release' is not signed.")

Update after a day of trying:
The error I've posted above is related to teamviewer debs I used to add to my debian LiveCD.
Going further, I've quickly got to a built squashfs, but the binary stage does not work. It's for debian, not ubuntu (again: live-build from ubuntu repos). So things I've done:

- add "--mode ubuntu" to lb config
- syslinux - builds but expects live.cfg[.in] in template, whereas ubuntu uses txt.cfg for kernel params. Result: casper/boot/ contains vmlinuz and initrd.img with version suffixes, but template (txt.cfg) has them without - cannot laod kernel
- grub(/2) - many tries, either missing package "grub", missing files, etc.

So again: HOW DO THEY BUILD IT.

Answer (score 0):

> But how are the LiveISOs being built in the first place?

Packages are pulled directly from the repositories.

> E: The repository 'file:/root/packages ./ Release' is not signed

[LiveBuild has their source code available](https://gitlab.devlabs.linuxassist.net/idms-linux/live-build/blob/724f5b4dc82d2b77279a8daad715878a14a41090/scripts/build/lb_chroot_archives). Line [246](https://gitlab.devlabs.linuxassist.net/idms-linux/live-build/blob/724f5b4dc82d2b77279a8daad715878a14a41090/scripts/build/lb_chroot_archives#L246)+ is of importance to you.
Signing is skipped if LB_APT_SECURE is "false". Maybe you do not have that in your configuration?

Comment: Actually I already got here.
My first post was with --apt-secure false. With --apt-secure true (or missing), it complains can't find gpg (which exists in chroot as "gpgv").
So my problem is that live-build FROM ubuntu repositories INSTALLED on an ubuntu system (tried 18.04 and 19.04) does not work and can't find hints online.
I've been doing debian for over a year.

Comment: So I did some debugging, and it seems the signing errors came from manually added .deb files (I tried adding teamviewer; reused working debian additions). Now I'm investigating "grub" at the binary stage (after squashfs compression).

Answer (score 0):

`live-build` sadly doesn't work properly for Ubuntu anymore. I made a tool to easily build a custom Ubuntu live ISO from scratch, because all other tools I know don't work properly with recent Ubuntu releases or don't generate clean ISOs without unnecessary files, or because they use an existing ISO or the currently running system.

My tool uses Debian's live-boot and live-config for the live system. See the `man` page for more information. **Tested** with Ubuntu 18.04 and 19.10. You can find it [here](https://launchpad.net/~bfeber/+archive/ubuntu/bulifs).

I based it on steps from [here](https://github.com/mvallim/live-custom-ubuntu-from-scratch).